# Ubuntu isn't booting

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, bash, graphics

My Ubuntu 21.04 isn't booting after setup proprietary drivers and reboot.
Driver: NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450
Video card: GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile
I've installed this driver in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers
And after i've booted my system, i saw an error.
Error:

/etc/profile/ line 27, Syntax error: unexpected end of file

profile code:

```
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
```

By the way, I don't see the line 27 in gedit in the file profile

Comment: Your output seems to be missing the first line of that file, and the last line, too. The first line is a comment: `# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))`. The final line is `fi`.

Comment: @user535733 thanks!

Comment: Has it solved your issue, please?

Comment: yes, this solved my question.